# Running ANT with a SeleneseTestCase results in java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit, selenium

Ok, so I'm trying to figure out why junit is failing during my ANT build when I try to run a class that extends a **SeleneseTestCase**. I can run the test manually without an issue. It's only when I try building and running it with ANT I get this problem.

I'm using Eclipse on the Mac with the latest version of:

```
selenium-java-client-driver-test.jar

selenium-java-client-driver.jar

selenium-server-standalone-2.0a7.jar
```

These are referenced in my global settings under the **ANT Global Settings**, and are imported properly in my **SeleneseTestCase** classes (I can run the testSuite.RegressionTest manually with no issues, as well as the test class itself). So somewhere I'm missing the linking between ANT and Selenium.

Any assistance, or further things to try would be greatly welcomed.

And if you're ever in San Diego (drinks are on me!!! dead serious :))

**Here is my Console Output:**

```
[junit] Testsuite: testSuite.RegressionTest
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
[junit] Null Test:  Caused an ERROR
[junit] null
[junit] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[junit] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/selenium/SeleneseTestCase
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
[junit]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
[junit]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
[junit]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
[junit]     at testSuite.RegressionTest.suite(Unknown Source)
[junit] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestCase
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
[junit]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
[junit]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
[junit] Test testSuite.RegressionTest FAILED
```

**UPDATE: You can see that the Selenium .jar files are loaded...**

[javac] [search path for class files: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/jsfd.jar,/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar,

**...[REMOVED IRRELEVANT LOADED CLASSES]...**

***/Applications/eclipse/plugins/junit-4.8.2.jar,/Applications/eclipse/plugins/selenium-java-client-driver-tests.jar,/Applications/eclipse/plugins/selenium-java-client-driver.jar,/Applications/eclipse/plugins/selenium-server-standalone-2.0a7.jar***]

**...[REMOVED IRRELEVANT LOADED CLASSES]...**

Comment: Have you run ANT with the verbose/debug on, you'll see what CLASSPATH it really loads.

Comment: @ karianna I've updated question with the part where it's loading the path to classes. From this output I'm assuming that the .jar files pertaining to selenium are being loaded properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like it's selenium, but rather ant that is giving you a headache. What version of ant are you using?

This definitely sounds like a classpath issue that could be generated from ant. I have spent many a wasted hour trying to figure out why my builds weren't working only to find out that there was some other classpath variable getting loaded when my task ran. I've even had the misfortune of loading an older version of ant (hidden deep within Weblogic) when I was explicitly calling a newer version. That was 4 wasted hours of my life...

My suggestion is to create a classpath variable in your ant script that explicitly names the jars you want to use, and run your ant task with '-v' (for verbose) to see what is really loaded at runtime.

The old saying goes 'if it smells like a duck, walks like a duck, and poops like a duck, then you've probably got a duck'

Comment: I found my issue resolved it self after I rebooted my Mac. I guess something with Eclipse (and the built in ANT v1.7.0.v200803061910) didn't recognize the classpaths and JARs I added until a reboot. I figured it was a classpath issue, but a reboot come on!!!